# Avoid giving phone number to Skype for Business (Lync)

Tags: android, phone, lync, skype-for-business

I installed latest version of Skype for Business (Lync). It seems I successfully entered into my account, but after that there is a question which I have to answer:

> What's your phone number?
>
> This lets you make and get work calls and join meetings from Skype for
>   Business.

[Next] button is inactive till I enter enough digits for a valid nymber.

I do not want to give my phone number to Microsoft.

How could I enter Lync without giving my phone number?

What if I installed the app on tablet without SIM card?

Comment: From your question, it seems that your phone number is a requirement to use the program. SU will not help you break through legitimate requirements.

Comment: Use a fake phone number?

Comment: @DavidPostill In this case, the user of the other number will receive some kind of information about my account :(

Comment: Not if you use a number that doesn't exist :)

Comment: I'm more miffed at all the permissions it 'needs'. I just want to use the text-chat portion for work, it shouldn't need *all* of file access, contacts, ability to make/receive real calls, microphone, calendar. I understand the later ones if they haven't coded their app properly, but the former are just egregious. If I never attach things from the phone, or solely use skype-contacts, it shouldn't need access just to run the app :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving an invalid number does the trick, as @DavidPostill stated.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Skype for Business, it must be recorded under a company.
Just enter the company's phone number, that's what I just did.

Comment: Sorry, not everyone has a company's phone.

Answer (score -1):

Skype for business (=SfB) is more as an chat only component. It includes (depending on your licenses) also some [VoIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) components. These are mostly part of a so called "SfB [Plus CAL](https://products.office.com/en-us/skype-for-business/it-pros)". With that plus call it is possible to use SfB as a normal phone device. That means if you wish to call a person you can do that with SfB and the person will see the phone number configured in SfB (more infos [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-and-receive-calls-using-Skype-for-Business-228e03aa-7361-4997-8dfa-1dd9bdc717f6)). The person can also give you a call on a configured SfB phone number and either your SfB App or your SfB client can receive the call.

So having that information in mind you can find the following help text inside the app (in the section where you should enter your phone number):

> Why we need your phone number: This lets you make and get work calls,
>   and join meetings from Skype for Business (If you use VoIP, and its
>   unavailable, this is your backup.)

So its not that Microsoft need it, its more that Skype for Business need that to improve the way it works.

Comment: 10x for clarification. But all things you mentioned are extra functionality which I (and many other people) do not want on my mobile. VoIP means Voice over IP, not Voice over Phone Number, so my phone number is not needed. If I want to use normal phone device, I prefer to use my mobile, not SfB. You mentioned "the (other) person will see the phone number configured in SfB" but I do not want this also. If I want someone to see my phone, I could share it manually.

Comment: Its not fully right, if you perform a emergency via VoIP in general (in SfB this is handled differently) but the connection was cut, so how should the emergency person (e.g. police, ambulance, ...) call you back? SfB isn´t only a chat solution which made it quite complicated to handle that. I see your point, but that's how SfB works. But if you are unhappy with how Microsoft handle that you can leave a Feedback [here](https://www.skypefeedback.com/) based on that Microsoft might change that somehow. In the meantime you can use another number (e.g. your office phone or backoffice number).

Comment: In this case, every app could pretend that it want to help you in emergency situations and because of this it MUST collect your phone number. And may be you home and work addresses (to send the ambulance there). And your credit card (to check whether its number is leaked into the net, and warn you)... All of them - MANDATORY :(

Comment: This is getting offtopic: But such emergency features are a [legal topic](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/voip-and-911-service) in most countries and the vendor need to follow. Via VoIP it isn´t that easy to detect your "[location](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413069.aspx)" or phone number, which is (by the way) possible when you use a normal phone (regardless if you try to hide the phone number). However that's not the main reason, the main reason for that is mentioned above :-)

Comment: I cannot agree that phone number is required because of legal issues, because regular Skype (not SfB) is a VoIP application and regular Skype does not want my number. Or regular Skype breaks the law? :)